# Ответ возращает ноль строковое представление объекта, как полyчить значение свойства(cryptography)?

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
import binascii
import rsa.randnum
import cryptography
from Crypto.Cipher import Salsa20
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet, MultiFernet
import base64
import qrcode
import image
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa, padding
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from authlib.specs.rfc7519 import jwt
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_public_key
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes import HashContext

private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
     public_exponent=65537,
     key_size=2048,
     backend=default_backend()
    )

class Key_Private():

    def __init__(self, private_key):
        self.__private_key = private_key

    def private_key_funct(self):
        return self.__private_key

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Your private key: {0}'.format(self.__private_key)

new_private_key = Key_Private(private_key)
print(new_private_key)
```

Выводит

```
Your private key: <cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.rsa._RSAPrivateKey object at 0x0317E8B0>
```

Нyжно что бы выводил приватный ключ примерно так "93HK38SNFP92313T03FJSNG0SNR" к примерy

Answer (score 0):

Вы выводите на экран объект класса, нужно просто указать нужное поле этого объекта:

```
print(new_private_key.__private_key)
```